# How to click on windows popup button using javascript?

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

I want to click on a button in a popup using javascript. When i search it with internet it only shows how to minimize. Is anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in dvance.

Comment: What have you so far tried?

Comment: I have tried with onkeydown option but the problem is initially the mouse option is in cancel button so when i use this onkeydown the process stopped. Hope u understand

Comment: which button you want to press?

Comment: There are two button in that windows popup. 1. Run 2. cancel. I want to click on Run.

Answer (score 1):

As the Pop up window is added dynamically you can use a delegate for that

```
$('body').on('click',"#buttonid", function(){
//write code here
})
```

Comment: i want to click on a windows popup button. Will it work?

Comment: As per your latest description, it is not web popup it is window popup alert while opening a file, i dont think it will work like that

Answer (score 1):

No you can not click on a Windows dialog button via pure Javascript.